# Is $\sigma$-finiteness really a necessary condition for this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Question: Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Suppose $f$ is integrable. Prove that given any $\varepsilon$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $$\int_A |f| d\mu < \varepsilon$$
whenever $\mu(A) < \delta$.

My Solution:

We use the fact that if $f \geq 0$ is measurable, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int (f\wedge n) \to \int f$, proved in Exercise 6.3. Since $|f|  = \max(f, 0) + \max(-f,0)\geq 0$ is a sum of measurable functions, it is itself measurable, and we can apply the result of Exercise 6.3. For simplicity, let $f_n = |f| \wedge n$. ( $f \wedge n = \min(f,n)$ )

Let $\varepsilon> 0$ be given and $A\in \mathcal A$. Then there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n > N$, we have 
$$ \int_A |f|- \int_A f_N d\mu < \varepsilon/2.$$
Since $f_n \leq n$ for all $n$, we know that
$$\int_A f_N d\mu \leq \int_A N d\mu = N\cdot \mu(A).$$
Choose $\delta = \varepsilon / (2N)$ and $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu(A) < \delta$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_A |f| d\mu &= \int_A f_N d\mu  + \int_A |f|d\mu - \int_A f_Nd\mu\\
&< N\cdot \mu(A) + \varepsilon/2\\
&< N\cdot \delta + \varepsilon/2\\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Is $\sigma$-finiteness really a necessary condition on $\mu$?

Comment: No it isn't, as your proof shows. (Nitpick: in the second to last sentence of the proof, you should say "Choose $\delta=\epsilon/(2N)$ and suppose $\mu(A)<\delta$".)

Comment: One could also note that any integrable function vanishes outside a set of $\sigma$-finite measure. So, as long as one is only talking about one (or countable many) integrable functions, one can usually restrict attention to a $\sigma$-finite subset. Thus, you can even deduce the "strong" version from the "weak".